# Is it common to contractually require that a professor works with other faculty members in their department?

Tags: collaboration, contract, adjunct-faculty

My adjunct contract states that I have to work with other professors and share information with them about the work. While I'd love doing that, I find it bizarre that it is part of my contract. This is particularly concerning to me since the head of the department has been pushing me to work with/learn from a certain faculty member whose teaching methods and approach are radically different from mine. I don't want to be "forced" to meet and chat with people just because the department's head thinks it would be good for me.

What would you do in a situation like this? Thank you!

Comment: Are they suggesting it because they think it would be good for you, or because they like this faculty member's methods and approach and hope you might adopt some of them for the good of the students/department? (note: someone may say the former when their actual motivation is the latter...)

Comment: You need to tell us which country, because "adjunct" means a very different thing in USA vs Canada vs elsewhere. Adjuncts in USA are often paid, adjuncts in Canada are *never*  (as far as I know) paid by the university.

Comment: I sat in this particular faculty's class as part of the hiring process. I will just say this: she collected students' phones because she couldn't control the class. Didn't have anything nice to say about the student body. Had assigned a reading for an undergrad intro level course that I read in an advanced MA level course. It was bizarre! So, I am stressing out!

Comment: It's an American University in Eastern Europe. I get paid...thankfully!

Comment: @user112640 Skoltech?

Comment: Did you go to school in the same Eastern European country? I am asking this since they often cover in undergraduate classes topics which in NA are covered at Master level.

Comment: I suspect that most departments don't want to hire an adjunct who would not interact with the rest of the faculty at all - just come in, teach the class, and leave. Kind of defeats the purpose of a 'faculty'. Just like few businesses want to hire somebody who will not interact with anybody else. Perhaps some previous hires had enough issues that they felt they needed to be explicit that interaction was required. But, if you really don't want to work with the people your boss wants you to work with, well, that may not end well.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone! I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 5):

You should learn from other faculty about their teaching methods.  In most cases, you should follow their advice.  Consider it an experiment.  If there is unambiguous evidence their advice is not effective, don't follow it.

Your alternative is to decline the contract.  If you are unwilling to try new teaching methods, I recommend taking that alternative.